# Online IMAP client with Gmail support?

Tags: web-apps, email, gmail

I swear I tried looking everywhere and I can't find anything like this. I am trying to find an online webmail app, which would let me connect several accounts and check them in one place - pretty much just like any regular desktop client does.

The features I'm looking for:

- full Gmail support
- IMAP support
- ideally should also sync Google Calendar

I've found some possible solutions, but none of them really cut it.

I know I can import IMAP accounts into my Gmail - but it's not perfect. Furthermore, I cannot import permanently another Gmail account but instead I have add it every time I want to access it.

Several open-source webmail clients were also tested - but none of them supported Gmail.

The closest I got to what I need is AOL's Alto Mail - but according to their website it supports max. 3 accounts.

I am willing to pay for a good tool which would suit my needs.